# Need to find the file dates of files in SharePoint library using Python SharePlum

Tags: python, file, date, sharepoint, shareplum

I would like to write a python script to get all the files of a SP Library and print the date of the file, using SharePlum but alternatives are welcome too.  Something like:

```
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/test')
    allfiles = folder.files
    for file in allfiles:
        print(file['Date'])
```

Comment: The Date is a column? Or do you want to get the file created time?

Answer (score 0):

I try to get the created time of the file for your reference:
[image]

```
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/images')
print(folder)
allfiles = folder.files
for file in allfiles:
    print(file["TimeCreated"])
```